# Calling Angular page from html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am calling Angular page from html page as follows: 
Problem here is it is not calling anything, please advise what I am doing wrong

**index.html:**

```
<p><input id="queryData" type="submit" value="click here!" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="queryData()"></p>
<script type=text/javascript src="app.js"></script>
```

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('application',[])
app.controller('appController', function($scope, appFactory){ 
$scope.queryData = function() {
appFactory.queryAllData(function(data)
{
// do something}}
})}
```

**Using Angular Factory**

```
app.factory('appFactory',function($http) {
var factory = {}
factory.queryAllData = function(callback) {
$http.get('/get_all_data').success(function(output){
callback(output)})
return factory } })
```

Comment: whatever the callback is doing, you need to return the result from it: `return callback(output)`, as well as the promise itself: `return $http.get(...`. This will give you a promise that you can use as `appFactory.queryAllData().then(function(data){...})`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My primary problem here is when I click its not going to `app.js` infact angular page. I have tried console.log to check execution but nothing is happening

Comment: possible typo: `script` - `<script` ?

Comment: no , checked everything. They both are same directory as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if your index.html looks exactly as shown above.

If not, You need to include

1. Include Angularjs library before app.js
2. Use ng-app to make angularjs recognise that part as angular app
3. Use ng-controller to attach the angular controller

Change your index.html to:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> My Angular App </title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="application"> <!-- Name used in angular.module("application") -->
        <p ng-controller="appController"> <!-- Controller --> 
            <input 
                id="queryData" 
                type="submit" 
                value="{{isLoading ? 'loading...' : 'click here!'}}" 
                class="btn btn-primary" 
                ng-click="queryData()" />
        </p>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have formatted your code and found few wrong "}" bracket closings and as of current angular 1.6 "success" callback from "$http" is changed to "then" "catch"

**app.js**

```
  var app = angular.module('application',[])

  app.controller('appController', function($scope, appFactory){ 
      $scope.isLoading = false;
      $scope.queryData = function() {
        $scope.isLoading = true;
        appFactory.queryAllData(function(data){
          // do something
          $scope.isLoading = false;
        }, function(error){
          $scope.isLoading = false;
          alert("error while loading data");
        })
      };
  });


  app.factory('appFactory',function($http) {
    var factory = {}
    factory.queryAllData = function(callback, errorCallback) {
      $http.get('/get_all_data').then(function(output){
        if(callback) {
          callback(output);
        }
      }).catch(function(error){
        if(errorCallback) {
          errorCallback(error);
        }
      });
    };
    return factory;
  });
```

I have tested the code and it's working

https://plnkr.co/edit/fa4KEO2CenLboBGIufVP?p=preview